# "column does not exist" when creating db

Tags: java, android, sqlite, illegalargumentexception

I'm trying to create an android app with a simple db (using the built-in sqlite db).
I have created a class that extends SQLiteOpenHelper:

```
public class DatabaseHandle extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "pass_db";
public static final String ALIAS_NAME = "name";
public static final String USER_NAME = "user";
public static final String PASSWORD = "password";
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "passwords";


public DatabaseHandle(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 2);

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
    Log.i("DatabaseHandle","inside onCreate");
    database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+ TABLE_NAME +" (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
            " "+ALIAS_NAME+" TEXT, " + " "+USER_NAME+" TEXT, "+PASSWORD+" TEXT);");
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(ALIAS_NAME, "Bank");
    values.put(USER_NAME, "maya123");
    values.put(PASSWORD, "xyz123");
    database.insert(TABLE_NAME, ALIAS_NAME, values);
}
```

and trying to get this data with a SimpleCurserAdapter:

```
public class MainActivityPasswords extends ListActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.user_list);
    database = (new DatabaseHandle(this)).getWritableDatabase();

    passwordCursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT _id, name, password FROM passwords ORDER BY name", null);
    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, 
            R.layout.row, 
            passwordCursor, 
            new String[]{DatabaseHandle.ALIAS_NAME, DatabaseHandle.USER_NAME, DatabaseHandle.PASSWORD},
            new int[]{R.id.alias, R.id.user_name, R.id.password}, 0);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    registerForContextMenu(getListView());
}
```

(this is partial code ofcourse)

when running the code i get:

> Java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Column 'user' does not exist.

Why is that? i can see clearly that i have 'user' column when opening the db file itself.

Help!

Comment: does not exists in cursor ...

Comment: you only get the result you ask for, in this case column _id, name and password

Comment: I think there's no reason to downvote this question. The question shows probably a frustrating attempt of a beginner trying to learn, also the question is clear, shows an attempt and the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to select the column user in your query

Change this

`passwordCursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT _id, name, password FROM passwords ORDER BY name", null);`

to this

`passwordCursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT _id, name, user, password FROM passwords ORDER BY name", null);`

Comment: And also thank you for a good experience from StackOverFlow! (although i got downvoted)

Comment: No problem :) By the way you can mark this answer as accepted so other users know this question is solved